# View results of a search in the same View AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, sqlite

First sorry for my bad english. I'm developing an app to be able to study and was putting everything on the controller, all queries and all. But then I decided to pass it to a service (vi which is the right to do so), only when I queries for my search service just stopped working.

In the template I list all registered categories and it has an input, which makes the search all registered establishments in the DB. I wish that when you do a search, the list simply update with a new, only listing the results of this search.

When I try to do a search, the following error appears:

`Object {message: "sqlite3_bind_null failure: bind or column index out of range", code: 0}`

And so are all related to this template code and the search:

**Service.js**

```js
app.service('Market', function($cordovaSQLite, DBA) {
  var self = this;
  
  self.allCategories = function() {
    return DBA.query("SELECT id, category_name FROM tblCategories")
      .then(function(result){
        return DBA.getAll(result);
    });
  }
  
  self.searchAll = function(nameSearch) {
    var parameters = [nameSearch];
    
    return DBA.query("SELECT id, place_name FROM tblPlaces WHERE place_name LIKE '%(?)%'", parameters)
      .then(function(result) {
        return DBA.getAll(result);
    });
  }
  
  return self;
})
```

**Controller.js**

```js
app.controller('CategoriesCtrl', function($scope, Market) {
  $scope.categories = [];
  $scope.categories = null;
  $scope.items = [];
  $scope.items = null;
  
  var nameSearch = '';
  $scope.searchkey = '';

  $scope.myClick = function (search) {
    nameSearch = search;
    console.log(nameSearch);
    
    $scope.searchResult = function(nameSearch) {
      Market.searchAll(nameSearch).then(function(items) {
        $scope.items = items;
        console.log(items);
      });
    }
    
    $scope.searchResult();
  };
  
  $scope.listAllCategories = function() {
    Market.allCategories().then(function(categories) {
      $scope.categories = categories;
    });
  }
  
  $scope.listAllCategories();
})
```

**Categories.html**

```js
<div class="bar bar-header item-input-inset">
  <label class="item-input-wrapper">
    <i class="icon ion-ios-search placeholder-icon"></i>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search" name="key" autocorrect="off" ng-model="searchkey">
  </label>
  <button class="button" ng-click="myClick(searchkey)">Buscar</button>
</div>
<ion-list>
  <ion-item ng-repeat="category in categories">{{category.category_name}}</ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Comment: The `myClick` function calls `Market.searchAll`. Where is that function?

Comment: @georgeawg It was the function `searchPlace`, I edited the file to the correct name. Sorry, I was doing some tests and forgot to return to the original name.